# Child action - adding multiple elements to

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a child action with the following code snippet:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var models = GetModelsFromDb();
    var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach (var model in models)
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(model.Id))
            counts.Add(model.Id, 0);

    return View(count);
}
```

The problem is that... `Add` sometimes throws `An item with the same key has already been added.` exception.
Could it be concurrency problem? I don't think since the code is in child action, and the dictionary is the local variable.

Comment: Question : this is possible that a "model" can be present twice for any reason when ou get it from your GetModelsFromDb method ? Edit1 : You can add GetModelsFromDBb() implemenation if is possible

Comment: Yes, That is why I am doing a check before adding element to dictionary.

Comment: Ok, i will write an answer

Comment: Note: the solution is not relevant (I know how to change code to make it work) - but I am curious why it happens in such a scenario.

Comment: @pwas did you try this `if (counts.ContainsKey(model.Id)) {//do other stuff}else { //add}`

Comment: @AfnanAhmad that doesn't make sense. It would do exactly the same.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. This code does not display the behavior you claim.

Comment: What you claiming is simply impossible. `return View(count);` is an obvious typo that would not compile (it would be `counts`) so copy you code exactly as it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

after you answer please change your implementation in GetModelsFromDb() to retrieve only distinct items :

You can do it by this way with linq :

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.id)
      .Select(g => g.First());
```

After that, you can quickly count your data like this :

```
var counts = models.Count();
```

**Edit 1 :**

If you can't for any reason do the distinct in your method :

```
var counts = models.Select(m => m.id).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: Ok, I know how to change the code to make it work. I am more curious why it doesn't work it scenario like I wrote. In multithread case - I know the problem has a chance to occur. But there is no chance that two threads access local variable in snippet like this.

Comment: I think something wrong with the containsKey, that sure there is any concurrence here. But someting black magic do thing that we can't understand ^^